Is there a config option or plugin in Neovim to turn off arrow symbol completion (e.g. => turns into ⇒)?
(Edit: This ended up being a feature of WezTerm, not neovim)
I'm fairly new to Neovim and used Kickstart to get me started with some nice features that I can customize as I learn and this is one of the first things I don't like.
I've tried searching through the manual and the web but maybe I don't know exactly what these are called.
For my terminal I am using Wezterm.
Example Image

This might be just the font you are using. That is called a ligature btw

@topsail thanks, this is completely off-topic but you just let me understand why the text I'm copy-pasting from a PDF is unclattered :O

Does this answer your question? How to disable LazyVim replacing operators => with arrows and other syntax replacements (note @JamesMcColl answer below)

As topsail mentioned this is actually a ligature that comes with the Wezterm terminal.
To turn it off I edited my wezterm config at ~/.wezterm.lua to include this line:
config.harfbuzz_features = { "calt=0", "clig=0", "liga=0" }
Which gets returned along with the other configurations when return config is called.
https://wezfurlong.org/wezterm/config/font-shaping.html

while your post is very useful (you spotted a duplicate for OP's question, which is very good) this information is not supposed to be expressed as an answer, but as a close-vote or a comment. Unfortunately you don't have enough reputation yet to perform those actions, but I for one understand your good intentions.

True, thanks for the advice. I was actually answering my own question quickly since it seemed to be a duplicate, but I dug into really fixing it and went ahead and edited my answer to hopefully be helpful for others!
